# I can't get my content to display in a page overlay

Tags: sxa

I'm trying to use SXA to display a form as an overlay on a page. I added the "Links Shown in Overlay" style to the form link.  When I click on the link, all I get is a blank, narrow box with a close button, none of my content is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you add a link component to a page, there is a CSS style option ‘show link in overlay’.
2. Link to a page that has a “blank” page design (i.e. no header, footer, etc) and contains an RTE or whatever desired component as its content (this page content is your modal window content).
3. Under Data -> Overlays, insert an Overlay Content item. This allows you to specify a desired height/width via pixel or percentage for your modal window.
4. Update overlay.scss for modal window styles.